# "java.lang.NullPointerException" thrown when ran as Junit test but not as Java Application

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

I am running a BDD Cucumber code as a Junit test and this tests keep failing with a javaLang nullPointerException. But the same code passes when i remove the cucumber tags and run as a java application, it passes. Can anyone help please.I have pasted the scripts and the error trace.
My appologies guys! Am new to java
Here's the code below:

```
package simpleSteps1;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;

public class TestOrderStepDef {

WebDriver driver = null;

@Given("^user is on logon page$")
public void user_is_on_logon_page() throws InterruptedException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\TestFolder\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Public\\TestFolder\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}

@When("^user enteres valid email$")
public void user_enteres_valid_email() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("test1@email.com");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}

@And("^User enters valid password$")
public void User_enters_valid_password() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passwd']")).sendKeys("password1");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("SubmitLogin")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}

@Then("^User should be logged in$")
public void User_should_be_logged_in() throws InterruptedException {
    String homePageText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center_column']/h1")).getText();
    System.out.println("Key HomePage text :" + " " + homePageText);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Braaaaaaaaaaaaavvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvooooooooooooo: AmLogged on!!!!!!!!");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}

@Given("^User is logged on$")
public void User_is_logged_on() {
    String homePageText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center_column']/h1")).getText();
    System.out.println("Key HomePage text :" + " " + homePageText);
    System.out.println("Am still logged on AmLogged on!!!!!!!! If: " + homePageText + "is still displayed here");

}

@When("^User performs a serach$")
public void User_performs_a_serach() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.id("search_query_top")).sendKeys("DRESSES");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchbox']/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

}

@Then("^User is taken to the correct page$")
public void User_is_taken_to_the_correct_page() {
    String sText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='categories_block_left']/h2")).getText();
    String sText1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='informations_block_left_1']/p/a")).getText();
    String sText2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='manufacturers_block_left']/p/a")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("CATEGORIES", sText);
    Assert.assertEquals("INFORMATION", sText1);
    Assert.assertEquals("MANUFACTURERS", sText2);
    System.out.println("Key Page Texts are :" + ":" + sText + ":" + sText1 + ":" + sText2);

}

@And("^User Clicks on Orders Page$")
public void Clicks_on_Orders_Page() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='left_column']/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]/a")).click();

}

@Then("^User should land on Order History Page$")
public void User_should_land_on_Order_History_Page() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    String OrderPage = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center_column']/h1")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("ORDER HISTORY", OrderPage);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

}

@Given("^user had completed search$")
public void user_had_completed_search() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center_column']/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}

@When("user clicks on Sign Out button$")
public void user_clicks_on_Sign_Out_button() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[2]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
}

@Then("^User is signed out of page$")
public void User_is_signed_out_of_page() {
    String LogoutPage = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login_form']/h3")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals("ALREADY REGISTERED?", LogoutPage);
    System.out.println("Logout page should have: " + LogoutPage);

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Here is the runner class:

```
package simpleSteps1;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature", 
                    format = {"pretty"})

public class TestOrderRunner {


}
```

Below is the console output trace:

```
Feature: General Page Navigation
1489409972904   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:42232
1489409973750   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.HQ7KCPRaWEBo
1489409973786   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args []
1489409973817   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:57692
1489409976216   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 57692
Mar 13, 2017 12:59:40 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Key HomePage text : MY ACCOUNT
Braaaaaaaaaaaaavvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvooooooooooooo: AmLogged on!!!!!!!!

Scenario: Verify Logon           [90m# src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:3[0m
[32mGiven [0m[32muser is on logon page[0m    [90m# TestOrderStepDef.user_is_on_logon_page()[0m
[32mWhen [0m[32muser enteres valid email[0m  [90m# TestOrderStepDef.user_enteres_valid_email()[0m
[32mAnd [0m[32mUser enters valid password[0m [90m# TestOrderStepDef.User_enters_valid_password()[0m
[32mThen [0m[32mUser should be logged in[0m  [90m# TestOrderStepDef.User_should_be_logged_in()[0m

Scenario: Verify Logout                       [90m# src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:9[0m
[31mGiven [0m[31mUser is logged on[0m                     [90m# TestOrderStepDef.User_is_logged_on()[0m
  [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
    at simpleSteps1.TestOrderStepDef.User_is_logged_on(TestOrderStepDef.java:62)
    at ✽.Given User is logged on(src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:10)
  [0m
[36mWhen [0m[36mUser performs a serach[0m                 [90m# TestOrderStepDef.User_performs_a_serach()[0m
[36mThen [0m[36mUser is taken to the correct page[0m      [90m# TestOrderStepDef.User_is_taken_to_the_correct_page()[0m
[36mAnd [0m[36mUser Clicks on Orders Page[0m              [90m# TestOrderStepDef.Clicks_on_Orders_Page()[0m
[36mThen [0m[36mUser should land on Order History Page[0m [90m# TestOrderStepDef.User_should_land_on_Order_History_Page()[0m

Scenario: Logout                      [90m# src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:16[0m
[31mGiven [0m[31muser had completed search[0m     [90m# TestOrderStepDef.user_had_completed_search()[0m
  [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
    at simpleSteps1.TestOrderStepDef.user_had_completed_search(TestOrderStepDef.java:107)
    at ✽.Given user had completed search(src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:17)
  [0m
[36mWhen [0m[36muser clicks on Sign Out button[0m [90m# TestOrderStepDef.user_clicks_on_Sign_Out_button()[0m
[36mThen [0m[36mUser is signed out of page[0m     [90m# TestOrderStepDef.User_is_signed_out_of_page()[0m

[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31msrc/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:9 [0m# Scenario: Verify Logout
[31msrc/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:16 [0m# Scenario: Logout

3 Scenarios ([31m2 failed[0m, [32m1 passed[0m)
12 Steps ([31m2 failed[0m, [36m6 skipped[0m, [32m4 passed[0m)
0m37.287s

java.lang.NullPointerException
at simpleSteps1.TestOrderStepDef.User_is_logged_on(TestOrderStepDef.java:62)
at ✽.Given User is logged on(src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:10)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at simpleSteps1.TestOrderStepDef.user_had_completed_search(TestOrderStepDef.java:107)
at ✽.Given user had completed search(src/test/java/simpleSteps1/TestOrders.feature:17)
```

Comment: WebDriver driver = null; Try to make it not null.... Welcome to SO.

Comment: WebDriver driver = null;
String homePageText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='center_column']/h1")).getText();
    
This will not work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - What is Line 62 and Line 107 in your test class?

Comment: I have tried that but its still not working. The code runs okay of the below point where the null pointer starts to kick in. It was finding and sending keys to all the elements before this point:      

         @When("^User performs a serach$")
   public void User_performs_a_serach() throws     InterruptedException {
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();              driver.findElement(By.id("search_query_top")).sendKeys("DRESSES");
     Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchbox']/button")).click();
     Thread.sleep(2000);